# import font using font-face failed

Tags: html, css

this is my style.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato-Regular';
  src: url("../../fonts/Lato-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("../../fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

html file

```
  <div class="text-center" style="font-family:Lato-Regular;color:#bef4f7;margin-top:-23px;font-size:32px">
                Text Example
            </div>
```

it failed and throw my errors

[image]

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your url() path seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your filepath. It leads into a folder named "assets". Maybe the filepath should be url("../fonts/Lato-Regular.woff") (one `../` less)  (or one more - just guessing here, but anyway, check the filepath)

Comment: I have another example that another programmer in my team did and it exactly the address and I put the same folder. still not works

Answer (score 0):

Check and see are the font files in your www/assets/fonts/ present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your path may be incorrect, the error you are getting is of that type. Consider showing the full path error on the image along with your CSS file and this can be confirmed 100%.

Also, may I suggest why not use google's CDN, it will give you greater cross-browser compatibility.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="text-center" style="font-family:Lato;color:#bef4f7;margin-top:-23px;font-size:32px">
  Text Example
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use fonts using CDN and its free font by google

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

or 
If you want to use locally than please paste all the downloaded fonts in proper folder it will work defiantly.